# Compare two tables in Java

Tags: java

I have to compare two tables and tell the user what's the difference between two tables.

Table1

```
------+---------
|Code | Label   |  
------+---------  
|a1   | a1text  |  
------+---------  
|b1   | b1text  |  
------+---------  
|c1   | bartext1|  
------+---------  
|e1   | foo     |  
-----+---------
```

Table2

```
------+---------  
|Code | Label   |  
------+---------  
|a1   | a1text  |  
------+---------  
|b1   | b2text  |  
------+---------  
|d1   | bartext2|  
------+---------  
|f1   | bar     |  
------+---------
```

**Comparison Info**
As you see in table1 for Code `c1` label is `bartext1` and for Code `d1` label is `bartext2`.
They are same expect last character. I have to put in my report they are same except last character. There are few rows in tables where there may be extra word or special character and its position is anywhere. Somehow I have to tell in the report both labels are same expect word is missing or there is a special character in one of them.Code is not important in report.

**More Info**
  This data is coming from Third party.Code is always unique, they are no duplicate Codes.
It may be possible that two codes have similar value 
like

Code | Label

ER4 |     i have a brother

WE3  |    i have a brother

**Expected Output should be**

1. Labels are different in two tables. Table1 label is : b1text  and Tabl2 label is: b2text.
2. Labels are different in two tables. Table1 label is : bartext1  and Tabl2 label is: bartext2.
3. label foo is missing in Table2.
4. label bar is missing in Table1.

Comment: Are you expect from  us full source code with unit-tests and installation script?

Comment: Are the tables sorted already? Are duplicate codes allowed? Are you allowed to use library routines such as Google Collections, Jakarta Common Collections or is this homework?

Comment: Are the tables sorted already?  NO   
Are duplicate codes allowed?    NO
use library routines such as Google Collections, Jakarta Common Collections   ? YES

is this homework? NO

Comment: How different do two rows have to be before you consider them "too different" to pair up? After all, "bartext2" and "bar" share a common prefix, would you consider them similar enough to pair up?

Also, don't you want to output the fact that although "bartext1" and "bartext2" are similar, they have different Code columns ("c1" vs "d1")?

I think your first task is to make your spec much clearer.

Answer (score 4):

This worked for me, please feel free to add salt to taste:

```
public final class ComparisonTest {

@Test
public void compare() throws Exception {
    String url = "your.url";
    String user = "your.user";
    String password = "your.password";
    // I am using Oracle here, but you can use any database
    Connection connection = getConnection(url, user, password, OracleDriver.class);

    ResultSet sourceResultSet = getResultSet(connection, "first_table");
    ResultSet targetResultSet = getResultSet(connection, "second_table");
    Map<Long, String> sourceIdHash = new HashMap<Long, String>();
    Map<Long, String> targetIdHash = new HashMap<Long, String>();

    try {
        long rows = 0;
        do {
            if (sourceResultSet.next()) {
                if (targetResultSet.next()) {
                    // Compare the lines
                    long sourceHash = hash(getRowValues(sourceResultSet, sourceResultSet.getMetaData()));
                    long targetHash = hash(getRowValues(targetResultSet, targetResultSet.getMetaData()));

                    sourceIdHash.put(sourceHash, sourceResultSet.getString(1));
                    targetIdHash.put(targetHash, targetResultSet.getString(1));

                    if (targetIdHash.containsKey(sourceHash)) {
                        targetIdHash.remove(sourceHash);
                        sourceIdHash.remove(sourceHash);
                    }
                    if (sourceIdHash.containsKey(targetHash)) {
                        sourceIdHash.remove(targetHash);
                        targetIdHash.remove(targetHash);
                    }
                } else {
                    // Add the source row
                    long sourceHash = hash(getRowValues(sourceResultSet, sourceResultSet.getMetaData()));
                    sourceIdHash.put(sourceHash, sourceResultSet.getString(1));
                }
            } else {
                if (targetResultSet.next()) {
                    // Add the target row
                    long targetHash = hash(getRowValues(targetResultSet, targetResultSet.getMetaData()));
                    targetIdHash.put(targetHash, targetResultSet.getString(1));
                } else {
                    break;
                }
            }
            if (rows++ % 10000 == 0) {
                System.out.println("Rows : " + rows);
            }
        } while (true);
    } finally {
        closeAll(sourceResultSet);
        closeAll(targetResultSet);
    }

    for (final Map.Entry<Long, String> mapEntry : sourceIdHash.entrySet()) {
        if (targetIdHash.containsKey(mapEntry.getKey())) {
            targetIdHash.remove(mapEntry.getKey());
            continue;
        }
        System.out.println("Not in target : " + mapEntry.getValue());
    }
    for (final Map.Entry<Long, String> mapEntry : targetIdHash.entrySet()) {
        if (sourceIdHash.containsKey(mapEntry.getKey())) {
            sourceIdHash.remove(mapEntry.getKey());
            continue;
        }
        System.out.println("Not in source : " + mapEntry.getValue());
    }

    System.out.println("In source and not target : " + sourceIdHash.size());
    System.out.println("In target and not source : " + targetIdHash.size());
}

private ResultSet getResultSet(final Connection connection, final String tableName) {
    String query = "select * from " + tableName + " order by pdb_key, organization_code, service_littera, day, resource_category";
    return executeQuery(connection, query);
}

private Object[] getRowValues(final ResultSet resultSet, final ResultSetMetaData resultSetMetaData) throws SQLException {
    List<Object> rowValues = new ArrayList<Object>();
    for (int i = 2; i < resultSetMetaData.getColumnCount(); i++) {
        rowValues.add(resultSet.getObject(i));
    }
    return rowValues.toArray(new Object[rowValues.size()]);
}

private final Connection getConnection(final String url, final String user, final String password, final Class<? extends Driver> driverClass) {
    try {
        DriverManager.registerDriver(driverClass.newInstance());
        return DriverManager.getConnection(url, user, password);
    } catch (Exception e) {
        throw new RuntimeException(e);
    }
}

private final ResultSet executeQuery(final Connection connection, final String query) {
    try {
        return connection.createStatement().executeQuery(query);
    } catch (SQLException e) {
        throw new RuntimeException(e);
    }
}

private final Long hash(final Object... objects) {
    StringBuilder builder = new StringBuilder();
    for (Object object : objects) {
        builder.append(object);
    }
    return hash(builder.toString());
}

public Long hash(final String string) {
    // Must be prime of course
    long seed = 131; // 31 131 1313 13131 131313 etc..
    long hash = 0;
    char[] chars = string.toCharArray();
    for (int i = 0; i < chars.length; i++) {
        hash = (hash * seed) + chars[i];
    }
    return Long.valueOf(Math.abs(hash));
}

private void closeAll(final ResultSet resultSet) {
    Statement statement = null;
    Connection connection = null;
    try {
        if (resultSet != null) {
            statement = resultSet.getStatement();
        }
        if (statement != null) {
            connection = statement.getConnection();
        }
    } catch (Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    close(resultSet);
    close(statement);
    close(connection);
}

private void close(final Statement statement) {
    if (statement == null) {
        return;
    }
    try {
        statement.close();
    } catch (Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}

private void close(final Connection connection) {
    if (connection == null) {
        return;
    }
    try {
        connection.close();
    } catch (Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}

private void close(final ResultSet resultSet) {
    if (resultSet == null) {
        return;
    }
    try {
        resultSet.close();
    } catch (Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}
```

}

Answer (score 2):

I'd create an abstraction for this Table object with an equals implementation that would hide all the details from clients.  Java's an object-oriented language, so best to use objects for their raison d'etre.

Comment: @duffymo Fine in general, but `equals()` is supposed to give `true` or `false` as output, not the one described above. So for this specific task one would have to implement a different comparison algorithm anyway.

Comment: So if you need to return a List<String> of reason codes, write another method.  The "think in terms of objects" point still stands.

Answer (score 1):

There's an Open Source Java framework that does that:

www.diffkit.org