# How to compare 2 database tables using Java

Tags: java, database, jdbc

I have a scenario here I need to compare 2 database tables using java

First Database table has

```
id  Name Salary
1   ABC  1000
2   XYZ  2000
3   LMN  3000
```

Second Database Table has

```
id Name Salary
4  PQR  5000
2  XYZ  2000
1  ABC  4000
3  LMN  2500
```

I had used list to compare but is there any other way to compare 1st table with the 2nd table using selenium java.

I want the output to be

```
Second table has 4 rows while 1 table has 3 rows (or vice versa)
1st table LMN salary is 3000 and second table LMN salary is 2500
```

Comment: There is no connection between Selenium and databases.

Comment: I have used JDBC to connect between selenium and database.I was able to retrieve the data also from database.Just need suggestions to compare Database tables using selenium

Comment: Selenium is to connect with html based UI. You can't use it to handle DB. `JDBC` is to connect between Java and DB, not Selenium and DB.

Comment: Ya sorry may be you can correct the question

Comment: @gurioso The author claims he is doing it with selenium, but he doesn't. Nothing in the code is from Selenium API. Calling it `driver` doesn't make it Selenium.

Comment: @gurioso All the code in the article you linked.

Comment: To compare two tables selenium might actually not be the tool of choice. E.g. [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2352865/compare-two-tables-in-java/17703935) are some approaches to do it.

Comment: @Suma You do not say what result you expect from the comparison. Do you want a list of things that are the same, or a list of things that are different? Both? What?

Comment: @Suma what kind of database are you using ?

Comment: @LoolKovsky microsoft sql

Comment: Is it a requirement to do the comparison in Java?

Comment: @LoolKovskyyes its a requirement

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would do the requested comparison in SQL directly. This will be faster. There are a couple of ways to do this depending on the results you need.

Since you are using Microsoft SQL you can retrieve the number of rows in the requested format by doing something like this:

```
SELECT 'The FirstTable has ' + cast((SELECT count(*) from FirstTable) as varchar(50)) + ' records, while the SecondTable has ' + cast((SELECT count(*) from SecondTable) as varchar(50)) + ' records';
```

For getting the differences between the tables you can do something like this:

```
SELECT * FROM FirstTable
UNION 
SELECT * FROM SecondTable
EXCEPT 
SELECT * FROM FirstTable
INTERSECT
SELECT * FROM SecondTable;
```

Then you can take ResultSet and compare the entries like this:

```
while (resultSet.next())
{

  int id= rs.getInt("id");
  String name= rs.getString("name");
  int firstTableSalary = rs.getInt("salary");

  rs.next();
  int secondTableSalary = rs.getInt("salary");

  console.log(String.format("The first table salary is %d, while the second table salary is %d, name=%s, id=%d", firstTableSalary, secondTableSalary, name, id);

}
```

I prepared [here](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!18/e1090c/1) a fiddle for checking the SQLs.

Comment: I am tester and I want to run these scenario to display what is the difference between both tables.I am using selenium cucumber framework with java

Comment: @Suma the above code can be used with Selenium. You need to put it in a WebDriver script

Comment: Yes got it.Thanks a lot

Answer (score 0):

Getting the salary differences is easier with SQL

```
String query = "select t1.name,t1.salary t1_salary, t2.salary t2_salary" +
    " from table1 t1, table2 t2 "+
    " where t1.id=t2.id and t1.name=t2.name and t1.salary!=t2.salary";
//this will give you a result set of all the names and salaries from the two tables 
//where the salaries differ. 
Connection conn = ...
try (Statement stmt = conn.createStatement()){
    ResultSet rs = stmt.executeQuery(query);
    while (rs.next()){
        String name = rs.getString(1);
        Integer t1Salary = rs.getInt(2);
        Integer t2Salary = rs.getInt(3);
         //do something with these values
    }
    rs.close();
```

Similarly, capture the table lengths with queries

```
    int t1Length = 0;
    int t2Length = 0;
    rs = stmt.executeQuery("select count(*) from table1");
    while (rs.next()){
        t1Length = rs.getInt(1);
    }
    rs.close();
    rs = stmt.executeQuery("select count(*) from table2");
    while (rs.next()){
       t2Length = rs.getInt(1);
    }
    rs.close();
     //do something with the lengths
}
conn.close();
```

Comment: I have 100s of records to compare.I cannot retrieve one by one and compare.Like salary I have 6 more columns to compare in both the tables

Comment: Is the set of columns being compared between tables always the same?

Comment: Yes columns in both the tables are always same